# In Modelica, how to call a variable in a different block without wiring the 2 blocks?

Tags: modelica

We are modeling various industrial component blocks, with each having CAPEX, labour cost, maintenance cost, total OPEX, etc. We would like to have 1 block, in the best case not wired to the other blocks, to account for the total OPEX, total CAPEX, total labour costs, etc. induced by the blocks present in a model : the number of blocks is not fixed. Is there a way of not connecting the blocks with a wire ?

In case there is no way, we found the solution of using the RealOutput y vector, as defined in Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.MO : nout is defined as the number of actual variables we would like to add up (e.g. if CAPEX, OPEX and maintenance are of interest, then nout = n = 3). However, we struggle for 2 points :

1. How can we pass a matrix through this RealOutput ? This would be useful for instance when the CAPEX has 3 values : estimated, optimistic and pessimistic.
2. How can we take up this y in only 1 block ? For now we managed to use n Modelica.Blocks.Math.MultiSum blocks to take up each variable separately, but is there a way of adding them up respectively, but in the same block ?

Thank you already for your much appreciated help and answers !

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this with the `inner`/`outer` construct and a custom connector with a `flow` variable for, e.g., your capex, as demonstrated in section 5.8 of Fritzson's book "Principles of Object-Oriented Modeling and Simulation with Modelica 3.3".

*I could have sworn there is already an example around that sums masses of components to a total, but I could not find it anywhere...*

```
package SO_69945088

model System
  FinancialAggregator fin_totals() "Collects financial info";
  inner CapexConn common_connection "autoshared connection";
  Component comp1(capex_info.amount={0, 3, 5});
  Component comp2(capex_info.amount={1, 10, 12});
  Component comp3(capex_info.amount={5, 6, 7});
equation
  //Conveniently collect financial info in fin_totals
  connect(common_connection, fin_totals.agg_conn);
end System;
connector CapexConn
  // the amount being a "flow" variables means all contributions
  // sum at a connection point.
  flow Real[3] amount;    
  // every "flow" variable should have a non-flow variable,
  // at least for "physical" connections. Let's add a dummy:
  Real [3] period;

end CapexConn;

  model CapexEmitter
    CapexConn conn;
    Real[3] amount = fill(0, 3);
    Real[3] period;
  equation
// Here you could also have more logic, like computing emitted capex
// depending on the period
    conn.amount = -amount; //negative because of sign of flow direction in connectors
    conn.period = period;
  end CapexEmitter;

model Component "Industrial component block with capex tracking"
  // (you would extend your other components from this to use it)
  outer CapexConn common_connection;  // make outside connection visible
  CapexEmitter capex_info;
equation
  // all Component instances automatically connect, without manual wiring
  connect(capex_info.conn, common_connection);
end Component;

  model FinancialAggregator
    CapexConn agg_conn;
    Real[3] capexsum; 
    Real period[3] = {1,1,1};
  equation
   capexsum = agg_conn.amount;
   period = agg_conn.period;

  end FinancialAggregator;
end SO_69945088;
```

Simulating `System` gives a `fin_totals.capexsum` of {6, 19, 24} (optimistic, estimated, pessimistic).

This should give you a starting point showing the principles.

Comment: It looks like this example is rather outdated. No class passes check in Dymola without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Such a remark would surely be more helpful if it offered concrete warning or error messages. 
On (current) OpenModelica 1.18 and MSL 4.0.0 this checks and simulates without any warnings or errors.  :-)

Comment: Sure. Interesting that Dymola and OpenModelica treat the code so different. Dymola nags about the connector not being balanced (you have 3 flow variables, but only 1 potential). `CapexEmitter` and `FinancialAggregator` do not check due to missing equations. You should set either `period` or `amount`. The problems in the other classes result from the ones before and they vanish when you fix them.

Comment: Fair points. I changed the connector to have 3 dummy periods, this should match now (and `System` runs). I also gave a default period to `FinancialAggregator`. I'm not sure how I should balance `CapExEmitter` without overdetermining `System`, do you have input on that?

Comment: Use a binding equation:  `Real[3] amount = fill(0, 3);`. `System` is allowed to overwrite it.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I thought I had tried that before.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, indeed in OpenModelica v1.18.0 it works like a charm !

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, please accept the answer, there should be a checkmark symbol above somewhere.

Comment: @Christoph I would actually have a follow-up question : I still need to somehow store the estimated, pessimistic and optimistic CAPEX for each block of my model (as described in my point 1.), because I want to operate some calculations with these variables. As there can be an arbirary and varying number of blocks, and I cannot use a flow variable as I don't want to simply add them up, I am struggling to find a way to do this.
Basically the idea would be to have n blocks that each give away 1x3 arrays, and wireless block that takes up each of the n arrays and concatenates them in a nx3 matrix.

Comment: Ah, ok, I went with this part of your question *"account for the total OPEX, total CAPEX, total labour costs"*, and attributed the bullet points to encountering the [x-y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174595) -- "total" => sum
I don't know how to solve this other problem, unfortunately. I'll think about it

Comment: I tried to make something work with the `connectorSizing` annotation (deriving `FinancialAggregator` from `PartialRealMISO`, thinking to dynamically accumulate connections. It didn't work, I think this is really meant for manually drawing wires and cannot be used automatically with `inner`/`outer`.